# Change color of div with several classes with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm a CSS beginner trying to customise my WordPress blog by using a custom.css file.

I'd like to change the color of a div but this div have several classes :

`<div class="container template-blog template-single-blog ">`

If I use the following code will it change the background of all the divs with at least one of these classes or only the div with at least these 3 classes ?

`.container .template-blog .template-single-blog  {
background-color: lightgreen;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your given markup:

`<div class="container template-blog template-single-blog ">`

This style:

```
.container .template-blog .template-single-blog  {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

Will not affect anything.  What that style declaration says is:
"For all elements with the class `container`, that have a descendant element with the class `template-blog` that contain children with the class `template-single-blog` elements, change the background of the element with the class `template-single-blog element`.

You could change the background of your div simply with this:

```
.template-single-blog  {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

Which will change **all** elements with the `.template-single-blog` class across the site, regardless if they have any other classes.

If you want to get more specific, you can do this:

```
.container.template-blog.template-single-blog  {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

Which will change **only** those elements that have *all three* classes.

Comment: One correction — _"...that have a **child** element with the class..."_ should be _"...that have a **descendent** element with the class..."_. It would apply to any descendent, not just direct children.

Comment: Would downvoters care to help me improve this answer by leaving a comment?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a several classes associated to an element e.g. the `<div>`, those classes will target that div element only.

However, if your `<div>` classes are being used anywhere else, it will however, change the background-color to lime green.

If you want one class to target one element and your not going to be using it anywhere, then maybe consider ids (`#unique`).

If you want to target that one element then consider doing the following:

```
.container.template-blog.template-single-blog {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

**Examples of usage**: http://jsfiddle.net/kjLfq8b4/

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
#uniqueItem {
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.oneClass {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
.twoClass {
  padding: 10px;
}
.threeclass {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.oneClass.twoClass.threeClass {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="uniqueItem">This is a unique Item</div>

<div class="oneClass">This is one class</div>

<div class="oneClass twoClass threeClass">This is multiple classes</div>
```

Comment: This is the best answer, but some examples would be helpful.

Comment: @cale_b - Just added some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces between classes names:

```
.container.template-blog.template-single-blog {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

This will mean that this style will be applied only when an tag matches with all the three classes.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selector is actually like this:
"class 'template-single-blog' which has an ancestor with class 'template-blog' which has an ancestor with class container"

The best option is to add a class to that div and make a CSS rule for that class:

```
.new-class {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

If adding a class isn't an option, you should try saying "a div that has all of those classes". It is written like this:

```
div.container.template-blog.template-single-blog {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the colour of all any div with one of these class names, you will want to add commas between the class names, like this:

```
.container, .template-blog, .template-single-blog  {
background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

Without the comma nothing will change.

Answer (score 0):

Will change nothing. You have selected the template-single-blog class in a markup like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="template-blog">
    <div class="template-single-blog">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Just change the background on one of the classes, will work if nothing overwrites it.

```
.template-single-blog  {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

or better add a new class
    .background-single-blog  {
      background-color: lightgreen;
    }

Comment: What "will change nothing"?

Comment: Your CSS code will not change the div that you want. Safer is to add a new class on your div like this:    .template-single-blog  {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

Comment: I know that.  I was suggesting that you improve your answer with that information.

Comment: My bad. Hope that my answer helped you.